# php File upload to directory failure, tmp_name and type not being generated

Tags: php, html

I am using apache 2.4 and PHP 7.3,
Here I am failing to upload images to the directory,

**PROBLEM: tmp_name and type not generated.**

tried functions:move_uploaded_file,copy

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
     Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
```

---

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {
   echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
   echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
echo $_FILES["userfile"]["error"];

print "</pre>";

?>
```

---

### OUTPUT:

Upload failed

```
Here is some more debugging info: Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => hope.png
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

 )
2
```

Comment: `[error] => 2` – go read up on what that means in the section of the PHP manual that explains file uploads!

Comment: [Please check php file upload error code here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)